# Сброс пароля MySQL в Windows

Tags: windows, mysql

Как сбросить пароль в MySQL на windows?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сброс пароля на MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/344374/%d0%a1%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

MySQLInstanceConfig.exe в папке с mysql там можно перенастроить

Comment: Там при применении настроек безопасности зависает, т.е. не может применить их (новый пароль).

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо найти папку с куда была установлена MySQL, найти в ней файл my.ini и в секции `[mysqld]` прописать директиву `skip-grant-tables`, которая потребуется стартовать без таблицы пользовательских привилегий

```
[mysqld]
...
skip-grant-tables
```

Далее можно обратиться к MySQL из под любого пользователя не указывая пароль

```
mysql -u root
```

После чего можно установить новый пароль пользователю root

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('новый пароль');
```

После установки пароля следует удалить директиву `skip-grant-tables` из my.ini и перезагрузить сервер MySQL.

Comment: Странно, но не работает этот способ.