# Сброс пароля на MySQL

Tags: windows, mysql

Как сбросить пароль в MySQL Windows?

Comment: Получилось? ([Восстановление пароля Root-а на Windows](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=159278))

Comment: нет не получилось mysql-nt.exe не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: Какая версия mysql ?

Comment: 5.5.23 версия

Answer (score 1):

В общем попробуйте [это](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"     --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"     --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

Путь к mysql посмотрите в свойствах сервиса

Answer (score 1):

[Вторая](http://wiki.keyweb.ru/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=97&nav=0) ссылка в [Яндексе](http://yandex.by/yandsearch?text=%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F+mysql+windows&tld=by&lr=157)...

Общий принцип:

Остановить mysql сервер и запустить с опцией --skip-grant-tables --user=root

Подключится:

mysql -u rootВыполнить команды:

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd‘) WHERE User=’root’;

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Действия в случае использования   mysql, plesk, windows:

If you have client's mysql service connected to Plesk you can just reset its password. Or look in psa db in misc table there are mysql_admin and mysql_password values.

Otherwise you can reset mysql password:

To reset Mysql admin's pass please follow these steps:

- Stop Mysql service in Administrative tools -> Services
- Start -> Run... -> cmd
- start it manually using this line:"%plesk_dir%\Databases\Mysql\bin\mysqld-nt.exe" -P3306 --skip-grant-tables
- minimize this windows
- Start -> Run... -> cmd
- connect this mysql instance: "%plesk_dir%\Databases\Mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -P3306 mysql
- Execute the following query:mysql> update mysql.user set password=password('new_password') where user='admin';mysql> exit
- Open Task Manager and terminate mysqld-nt.exe process
- Start Mysql service from Services window

After that you can use this new password in Plesk CP -> Databases -> on Mysql

As server address you can use localhost and 3306 as portand login/pass will be admin/<password you set before>.

Не забудьте остановить службу, потом запустить.

Переводить надо?)))

Comment: еслиб не надо было переводить, то свой вопрос ТС мог бы задать гуглу в тойже самой форме)

Comment: пост 2013 года... хотел попробовать перевести -- но едет разметка :( пусть останется в такой форме, оно всё лучше, чем то, что получалось в итоге.